# Page Rank not showing correctly everywhere?

Tags: seo, pagerank

Okay, so I checked the page rank again, and http://www.namhost.com's page rank is now 4. But I get this warning:

```
Google Pagerank for: http://www.namhost.com  4/10
Pagerank is valid!
Attention! This domain has a very little quality backlinks and you run the risk of the domain losing it's page rank on the next Google pagerank update!
```

I used: http://www.checkpagerank.net

I then used a few other checkers: http://www.whatsmypagerank.com/pagerank-checker.php
This one found my page rank to be zero.

So my questions are

1. which one is correct?
2. why are they different?
3. should I attempt get rid of the +- 40 000 BAD backlinks I have, or should I focus my efforts on getting 40 000 GOOD backlinks ? i.e. Will the good backlinks trump the badlinks (copyright pending)?

Answer (score 7):

> which one is correct?

Neither. The PageRank they show is old information. PageRank is updated daily but the PageRank you see in the Google toolbar (which is the only official PageRank by the way) is updated only periodically. So you never actually never know your real PageRank.

> why are they different?

Because they aren't the real PageRank. They're probably trying to get it from Google's servers like the Google toolbar does but one is clearly failing and the other probably is not.

> should I attempt get rid of the +- 40 000 BAD backlinks I have, or should I focus my efforts on getting 40 000 GOOD backlinks ? i.e. Will the good backlinks trump the badlinks (copyright pending)?

Here's two better ideas:

1. Stop focusing on PageRank. It has so little value that the time you spent writing this question was more then PageRank is worth.
2. Focus on improving your content. Quality content gets quality links. Period.

Comment: You could put those last two comments into the tag wiki for pagerank.

Comment: Yes, but my immediate problem is being banned for having loads of bad backlinks. Being penalised for that, means any other seo efforts are useless, so i do need to focus on this?

Comment: Who says you're you're getting bad for having bad badlinks? Who says those backlinks are bad?